# Unexpected stiff system error

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

Let there be the following functions

```
ya[t_, x_] := Cosh[t*x]
za[t_, x_] := Sinh[t*x]
wa[t_, x_] := x*Sinh[t*x]^2
```

One can verify that the following PDE's hold

```
D[ya[t, x], t] == wa[t, x]/za[t, x]

D[za[t, x], t] == 
 D[wa[t, x], x]/
   D[ya[t, x], x] + (x Cosh[t x] - (
    Csch[t x] (2 t x Cosh[t x] Sinh[t x] + Sinh[t x]^2))/t)

D[wa[t, x], t] == 
 D[wa[t, x], x]/
   za[t, x] + (2 x^2 Cosh[t x] Sinh[t x] - 
    Csch[t x] (2 t x Cosh[t x] Sinh[t x] + Sinh[t x]^2))
```

i.e. that they are evaluated to `True`.

I would expect that the following `NDSolve` code would give `ya`, `za` and `wa` as an output:

```
mol[n_Integer, o_: "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}} 

Monitor[AbsoluteTiming[

  s = NDSolve[{

      D[y[t, x], t] == w[t, x]/z[t, x],
      D[z[t, x], t] == 
       D[w[t, x], x]/
         D[y[t, x], x] + (x Cosh[t x] - (
          Csch[t x] (2 t x Cosh[t x] Sinh[t x] + Sinh[t x]^2))/t),
      D[w[t, x], t] == 
       D[w[t, x], x]/
         z[t, x] + (2 x^2 Cosh[t x] Sinh[t x] - 
          Csch[t x] (2 t x Cosh[t x] Sinh[t x] + Sinh[t x]^2)),

      w[t, 2] == wa[t, 2], y[t, 2] == ya[t, 2], z[t, 1] == za[t, 1],
      w[1, x] == wa[1, x], y[1, x] == ya[1, x], z[1, x] == za[1, x]

      }, {y, z, w}, {x, 1, 2}, {t, 1, 2}, Method -> mol[81], 

     EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = 
        Row[{" t = ", CForm[t]}])];], currentTime]
```

However an error occurs:

> NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 1.071045212039208`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

I plotted `ya`, `za` and `wa` and they did not seem to be stiff at all, at least not at `t == 1.071045212039208`. So I think that there must be some kind of spelling mistake in my code.

I have not yet been able to find out what is going on. This is a real problem since it is this same error that I keep getting in other circumstances where an analytical solution is not available.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the method you chose, not in the equations. If you remove the `Method` option from `NDSolve` and let it choose for itself, it finds a solution in a fraction of the time and with no errors. A plot of the interpolation function obtained for `y` is practically indistinguishable from `ya`, so the solution seems valid too. See: `Plot3D[Evaluate[{y[t, x], ya[t, x]} /. First@s], {t, 1, 2}, {x, 1, 2}]`.

Comment: I tried without `Method` but got `NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 1.`.`

Comment: Is it possible that you had not defined `ya`, `wa`, and `za` when you ran this last try?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry..